# Replacing old ACT library classes and methods

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I've got a project from a few years ago that uses the Ajax Control Toolkit and I'm trying to update it. [Per the website,](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ToolkitScriptManager%20Removed%20in%20v15.1%2C%20Use%20ScriptManager) when using the latest version of the library (v15.1) you need to replace instantiations of AjaxControlToolKit.ToolKitScriptManager with AjaxControlToolKit.ScriptManager. Unfortunately, neither class exists according to Visual Studio. It does recognize the AjaxControlToolKit namespace. The project is being converted from .Net 2 to .Net 4.5 and 4.5 is currently the targeted framework version in the project properties.

Why won't Visual Studio find the class? What can I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ScriptManager in not a part of Ajax Control ToolKit, this is the [standard ASP.NET Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I suppose this means that any methods called by that class will not work either?

Comment: @broguesquadron Not any.
AjaxControlToolKit.ToolKitScriptManager is derived from ScriptManager, so only method introduced by ToolKitScriptManager itself will fail. 
Try to compile and run the application to see what happens.